# How much does Diffusal Blade slow enemies?

Tags: dota-2

I'm curious on how Diffusal Blade slows. The in-game description doesn't give any real details, and simply says something along the lines of "Slows enemy unit".

How great is the movement speed reduction percentage? Does it stack with other slows like Orb of Venom or Skadi?

Answer (score 6):

According to this website:
http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Diffusal_Blade

The movespeed **slows 100%**, and then the slow decreases in **0.8 second intervals**, so it slows for **100%/80%/60%/40%/20%**, **going one step down every 0.8 seconds**.

This page also has some info on the buff: PURGE
http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Purge

As for the slow stack, I believe it does but I don't think you can slow a hero beyond 100%. That means, once the slow goes 80% or lower then you can see the effects of the other stacked slow items.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit trickier than that. The slow isn't a fixed percentage.

The slow starts at 100%, and is recovered over 4 seconds after. If the unit is not an hero the unit is stopped for 3 seconds and then recovers their speed in 1 second afterwards.

As for stacking, all slows stack additively following this pretty complicated formula: http://wiki.teamliquid.net/dota2/Movement_Speed#Movement_Speed_Formula

See also: http://wiki.teamliquid.net/dota2/Diffusal_Blade